# get the index of search item in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contain a column

```
            combine
0   (43,FR,html5 full skinz html5)
1   (43,FR,mobile m-skinz2)
2   (43,FR,mobile m-skinz2 plus)
3   (43,FR,mobile m-skinz2 swipetosite)
```

I am looking for a way to find a string S in the combine column and get its index.

Is there any python function to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.index[df['combine'].str.contains(S, regex=False)].tolist()
```

This will generate you an index numbers list of 'combine' containing string S